# How to add toolbar to a master detail application in iOS

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I would like to add a toolbar to a master detail application based on a UISplitViewController.

The toolbar is meant to be always visible at the bottom of the screen.

How can I retrofit this design in a master-detail based app containing a UISplitViewController to include the toolbar at the bottom of the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you want to support iOS 7, because with iOS 8 this is done within the enclosing UINavigationController.